# Convert Integer to Byte Array In VB6

Tags: vb6, arrays

How do I convert an Integer value to a Byte Array in Visual Basic 6? I can obviously do this very easily in .NET with the BitConverter, but I couldn't find anything similar in VB6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for you:
http://www.convertdatatypes.com/Convert-Byte-Array-to-Integer-in-VB6-VBA.html

Comment: I am probably just missing it, but where is it specifically that it explains how to convert an integer into a byte array?

Comment: Sorry about that. The answer is fixed now.

Answer (score 3):

You can `LSet` between two UDTS, you can use CopyMemory, you can use a TLB that gives access to parts of the runtime not normally exposed, etc.  There are multiple options here.